# Get max timestamp values on joined table SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables like so:

OBJECT_VIEW table:

| view_id | object_id | object_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1423 | 12 | ob1 |
| 1423 | 15 | ob2 |
| 1423 | 17 | ob3 |
| 2499 | 15 | ob2 |

OBJECT_EXEC table:

| object_id | execution_time |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 16-oct-22 00:01:00 |
| 12 | 18-oct-22 00:07:00 |
| 15 | 14-oct-22 00:01:00 |
| 17 | 11-oct-22 00:01:00 |
| 17 | 13-oct-22 00:01:00 |
| 12 | 15-oct-22 00:01:00 |
| 15 | 13-oct-22 00:01:00 |
| 12 | 16-oct-22 00:01:00 |
| 17 | 17-oct-22 00:01:00 |

Id like to get a result where I see the latest execution per object that exist within a view. (The view_id - object_id is a many-to-many relationship.)
So only one of each object_id in the resulting table with the max value of execution_time.
This needs to also be filtered by view_id, so I can check the max execution times per view.

Like this:

| object_id | object_name | execution_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | ob1 | 18-oct-22 00:07:00 |
| 17 | ob3 | 17-oct-22 00:01:00 |
| 15 | ob2 | 14-oct-22 00:01:00 |

So far, I've tried using MAX() and group by, but my output is not showing the max_execution per object_id ONLY. It's showing multiple of the same id. What am I missing?

```
SELECT ov.object_id, ov.object_name, MAX(oe.execution_time) AS "LAST_EXECUTION"
FROM OBJECT_EXEC oe 
JOIN OBJECT_VIEW ov
ON oe.object_id = ov.object_id
WHERE ov.view_id = 1423
GROUP BY oe.execution_time, ov.object_id, ov.object_name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be including `execution_time` in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT ov.object_id, ov.object_name, MAX(oe.execution_time) AS "LAST_EXECUTION"
FROM OBJECT_EXEC oe 
INNER JOIN OBJECT_VIEW ov
    ON oe.object_id = ov.object_id
WHERE ov.view_id = 1423
GROUP BY ov.object_id, ov.object_name;
```

Comment: Wow.. simple as that... thank you very much